Bad map display in QGIS
I created a custom projection in QGIS, but there is a problem with its display, especially at the poles of the planet (photos in the link), from what I noticed it is only a visual problem (video in the link), "hitboxes" work normally
QGIS version: 3.36.1
Video and images: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HUiVHWQ9ZPwW-z8m6me4SKXp87MQqYrs?usp=sharing
Code:
+proj=ortho
+lat_0=90
+lon_0=0
+x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6383699.81 +b=6383699.81 +units=m +no_defs

How to fix it?
